# error 501 on ftp.retrbinary (ftplib)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftplib

I'm coding a script to check a FTP directory and download the new files. This is part of the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os

ftp = FTP(ftp_lance)
ftp.login(login, password)
ftp.cwd('xxxxxx')

FTP_list = ftp.nlst()

lista_diferenca = [file for file in FTP_list if file not in local_list]

for file in lista_diferenca:
    local_filename = os.path.join(cache, file)
    ftp.retrbinary('REST ' + file, open(local_filename, 'wb').write)
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\Istari\Radagast\Radagast.py", line 44, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('REST tabela14_pag5.pdf', open(local_filename, 'wb').write)
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\ftplib.py", line 414, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\ftplib.py", line 339, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
error_perm: 501 Bad parameter. Numeric value required
```

I check several sites searching for this kind of error and find nothing. It seems that my retrbinaty is broken, but the arguments looks right (first the 'Rest' + file, and then the callback function).

Some idea about my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the FTP command `RETR`, not `REST`:

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, open(local_filename, 'wb').write)
```